# how to merge two template column in kendo mvc?

Tags: model-view-controller, merge, kendo-ui

is there a way for merge two column in kendo mvc grid?
this is my code, i have two template column Edit and Delete
i want merge these two columns

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
          .Name("Grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
          columns.Bound(c => c.Name).Title(GlobalResources.Name).Width(30);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Description).Title(GlobalResources.Description).Width(80);

          columns.Template
          (
            @<text>
                <a href="Edit/@item.ID" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
                    <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
                </a>
            </text>

          ).Width(5);
              columns.Template
          (
                @<text>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="deleteRecord(this, @item.ID);">
                        <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
                    </a>
                </text>
          ).Width(5);
          })
      )
    )
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add both links in one column

```
columns.Template
(
    @<text>
        <a href="Edit/@item.ID" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">
          <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" onclick="deleteRecord(this, @item.ID);">
          <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
        </a>
    </text>
)
.Width(12);
```